# Weil divisors associated to Cartier divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $X=\{x_3^2=x_1^2+x_2^2\}\in \mathbb{P}^3$, let $L_1=Z(x_2,x_1+x_3)$, and $L_2=Z(x_2,x_1-x_3)$.
>   I don't quite understand how to get that $\operatorname{div}(x_2)$ is associated to $[L_1]+[L_2]$ and $\operatorname{div}(x_1+x_3)$ is associated to $2[L_1]$.

I think this means $\operatorname{ord}_{L_1}(x_2)=\operatorname{ord}_{L_2}(x_2)=1$ and $\operatorname{ord}_{L_1}(x_1+x_3)=2$. But I think $\operatorname{ord}_{L_1}(x_2)=\operatorname{ord}_{L_2}(x_2)=2$ as well, since we just need to calculate the length of $((k[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x^2_1+x^2_2-x^2_3))_{(x_2,x_1+x_3)})/(x_2))$, and since $\overline{(x_2)} \subset \overline{(x_2,x_1+x_3)} \subset (k[x_1,x_2,x_3]/(x^2_1+x^2_2-x^2_3))_{(x_2,x_1+x_3)})$, $\operatorname{ord}_{L_1}(x_2)$ should be 2, why is this not true?

This comes from Gathmann's notes on [Algebraic Geometry](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf), page 179.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll write $A$ for the ring $$\left(\frac{k[x_1, x_2, x_3]}{(x_1^2 + x_2^2 -x_3^2)}\right)_{(x_2, x_1+ x_3)}.$$ There seems to be an error in your calculation of the length of $A/x_2$. In particular, we have that the ideals $(x_2)$ and $(x_2, x_1+ x_3)$ of $A$ are actually equal. This is because $x_1-x_3$ is invertible in $A$, so we have that $$x_1 + x_3 = -\frac{x_2^2}{x_1 - x_3}$$ which is already in the ideal $(x_2)$.